# Link Shortner using preg_match

Tags: php, regex

My code is:

```
if (!preg_match('^http(s)?://(*)?\.mysite.com(\*)^', $url))
{
  echo "<strong>Error</strong>: Invalid mysite.com link or could shorten link";
}
```

and I got:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: 
  Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 12
```

I am working on a link shortner, similar to **bit.ly**, but I only want it to shorten links from my specific site.

I need some help with this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The asterisk or star tells the engine to attempt to match the preceding token zero or more times.

```
if (!preg_match('^http(s)?://(*)?\.mysite.com(\*)^', $url))
                              ↑
                       nothing to match
```

I believe your regex pattern contains multiple errors. I suggest you to go with

```
if (!preg_match('/^https?:\/\/(?:[a-z\d-]+\.)*mysite.com(?:(?=\/)|$)/i', $url))
```

Comment: Why is it always the little almost unnoticeable things!.
Thanks guys is working now!

Comment: Why did you leave out the end-of-string markers??? This could lead to a potential attack!

Comment: @JanDvorak - I believe OP wants to check if `$url` contains domain name `mysite.com`, so the tailing part of the `$url` is not important.

Comment: But the leading part is! And you didn't include the respective marker in the revision I commented.

Comment: @JanDvorak - It is hard to understand what really OP wants. You are welcome to post your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is here:

```
if (!preg_match('^http(s)?://(*)?\.mysite.com(\*)^', $url))
                              ^
```

You have used the `*` quantifier but you've not specified to what should this quantifier be applied to. You probably wanted `.*` there in place of just `*`.

Comment: One more thing: the regex is missing its delimiters. It needs to be wrapped inside a pair of.

Comment: OP's pattern use `^` as a delimiter

Comment: @Ωmega in which case it's missing the start of regex.

Comment: @Ωmega and that's why he came here.

Comment: @codeaddit
You seem to be the most knowledgable, how can I get that error do display in a div
`<div id="error"> <span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"></span> <strong>Error:</strong> <span id="error-text"></span> </div>`